# qplatformdefs.h with cmake

Tags: linux, qt, cmake

I'm trying to compile my Qt program with cmake but I've got an arror when compiling [qzip.cpp](https://raw.github.com/chindit/dadaword/master/qzip.cpp) :

> qzip.cpp:57:27: error fatal: qplatformdefs.h:  No such file or directory

I've added these lines in *CMakeLists.txt* but it didn't work :

> IF (QT_LIBRARY_DIR AND NOT QT_MKSPECS_DIR  OR  QT_QMAKE_CHANGED)
>
> EXEC_PROGRAM( ${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE}
>
> > ```
> > ARGS "-query QMAKE_MKSPECS"
> >
> > OUTPUT_VARIABLE qt_mkspecs_dirs )
> > ```
>
> # do not replace : on windows as it might be a drive letter
>
> # and windows should already use ; as a separator
>
> IF(UNIX)
>
> > ```
> > STRING(REPLACE ":" ";" qt_mkspecs_dirs "${qt_mkspecs_dirs}")
> > ```
>
> ENDIF(UNIX)
>
> SET(QT_MKSPECS_DIR NOTFOUND)
>
> FIND_PATH(QT_MKSPECS_DIR qconfig.pri PATHS ${qt_mkspecs_dirs}
>
> > ```
> > DOC "The location of the Qt mkspecs containing qconfig.pri"
> >
> >  NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
> > ```
>
> ENDIF (QT_LIBRARY_DIR AND NOT QT_MKSPECS_DIR  OR  QT_QMAKE_CHANGED)
>
> SET( QT_INCLUDES ${QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_MKSPECS_DIR}/default ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} )

So, how can I add a link to **qplatformdefs.h** in my CMakeLists.cpp?

Thanks a lot.

**P.S.:** I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 32bits

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add this to your CMakeLists.txt:

`include_directories(${QT_MKSPECS_DIR}/default)`

Answer (score 1):

You may have already found the answer, but in case you have not found it here is the thing:

In my Fedora, this file is located in **/usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64**.
Assuming that its the same location in Ubuntu, you should add this dir to the include_directories();

```
include_directories( lots_of_dirs "/usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/")
```

I hope I have helped.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a fragile solution.  If the code is checked out on another platform, won't it break?  Is there some way of getting Qt to tell CMake where this file is?